# Can OLTU provide JWTs as Access Tokens

Tags: java, oauth, jwt, oltu

OLTU, in it's limited documentations has an example of serving access tokens based on generated UUIDs.
See [here under Token Endpoint](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OLTU/OAuth+2.0+Authorization+Server)

It also has an example of using JWTs (Java Web Tokens) for server-to-server authorization [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OLTU/OAuth+2+server+to+server), but only as a bearer token in an *authorization grant request*

Nowadays it is common to use JWTs as the access tokens themselves (saves unnecessary trips to the authorization server)

Is there any reason this is not provided by OLTU out-of-the-box?
It seems it would be easy to implement a custom solution, but I would have expected there to be a JWT-based implementation of the [ValueGenerator interface](https://oltu.apache.org/apidocs/oauth2/reference/org/apache/oltu/oauth2/as/issuer/ValueGenerator.html) so that the standard implementation of the token issuer, [OAuthIssuerImpl](https://oltu.apache.org/apidocs/oauth2/reference/org/apache/oltu/oauth2/as/issuer/OAuthIssuerImpl.html) could generate one.

Is anybody doing this with OLTU?

Comment: We're looking into doing more or less the same and I have a hard time finding out what the Oltu JWT code does or does not do already. The documentation is pretty nonexistent. Did you have any success with this?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, OAuth's spec doesn't force to use a JWT, so the implementation of Oltu, respecting the spec and aiming to be the most compliant possible, use a random string that doesn't contain any **out-of-spec** informations in it.

From the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749):

> Access tokens can have different formats, structures, and methods of
> utilization (e.g., cryptographic properties) based on the resource
> server security requirements.  Access token attributes and the
> methods used to access protected resources are beyond the scope of
> this specification